# Responsive design in mobile application

Tags: jquery, user-interface, web-applications, responsive-design, mobile-application

I have learnt recently about basic of utilizing responsive design. Throughout Google, responsive design is about making web applications responsive per device screen/browser.

My understanding is that responsive design helps to make web applications responsive when accessed through browsers not on mobile apps.

How we can make mobile apps responsive as well so that apps are accessible when installed on screens of different dimensions?

Is there any other technology to make mobile applications responsive like web application on browser?

Comment: are you talking about native app? which we install in our device?